# What is an Alternate Setting in a USB interface?

Tags: usb

What is an Alternate Setting?
Example of device that needs them?

The USB spec has a lot of talk about them, but never tells what one is and - most importantly - why I would use one.
I never saw a USB device that uses alternate settings.

Comment: By the way: If you are reading the USB spec, you will probably not understand much, because this document is of bad writing quality and lacking examples. If you are learning USB I recommend this excellent tutorial: http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk

Comment: "I never saw a USB device that uses alternate settings."  Pretty much every USB audio device uses them for different bandwidth settings (16-bit 44.1 kHz, vs 24-bit 96 kHz, for instance.)  Probably same for video, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Alternate setting` is used to provide the advantage of having two configurations on the fly even though the device has only one configuration.

The alternate setting of a `USB` interface is define by the `bAlternateSetting` attribute in the Standard Interface Descriptor. A `USB` interface with an alternate settings can be used in two mode. For example a `USB` interface endpoints may act as `INTERRUPT` pipes in normal settings, but might act as `BULK` pipe in alternate settings providing you the facility of two different mode on the same interface. You just have to send a `SetInterface` request to activate a settings. I myself didn't have to use it much though. And I think normally device drivers don't tend to use it as I couldn't find out any example driver.

You can look at this [link](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) for more details.

Comment: You have a typo in your answer. It is defined in the Interface descriptor, not in the device descriptor.

Comment: I suppose you found your answer here: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml They use exactly the same example as you do. But you did not add the image that they have there.

Comment: So an Alternate setting is just another interface which is mutually exclusive with the default interface?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the specs, a given USB host expects to install ONLY ONE specific driver for a given VID/PID identifier. Now, some devices provide different interfaces, which would require a completely different driver. For example a USB modem that also implements a usb storage to provide installation software.
One mechanism that allows the host to select either the MSC interface (storage) or the SSP interface (modem) is the alternate setting configuration.