# Decoding USB Descriptor

Tags: usb

I am trying to understand USB descriptors. For exploration I acquired my USB headphone descriptor using usbtreeview software. My understanding of descriptor hierarchy is:

1. The device has only one descriptor
2. Under Device descriptor, we may have one or more Configuration descriptor.
3. Each configuration may have one or more interface descriptor
4. and finally each interface descriptor may have one or more endpoints descriptor.

```
    ---------------------- Device Descriptor ----------------------
bLength                  : 0x12 (18 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x01 (Device Descriptor)
bcdUSB                   : 0x200 (USB Version 2.0) -> but device is Full-Speed only
bDeviceClass             : 0x00 (defined by the interface descriptors)
bDeviceSubClass          : 0x00
bDeviceProtocol          : 0x00
bMaxPacketSize0          : 0x40 (64 bytes)
idVendor                 : 0x046D (Logitech Inc.)
idProduct                : 0x0A38
bcdDevice                : 0x0117
iManufacturer            : 0x01 (String Descriptor 1)
 Language 0x0409         : "Logitech Inc."
iProduct                 : 0x02 (String Descriptor 2)
 Language 0x0409         : "Logi USB Headset H340"
iSerialNumber            : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 Configuration)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 01 00 02 00 00 00 40 6D 04 38 0A 17 01 01 02   .......@m.8.....
                           00 01                                             ..

    ------------------ Configuration Descriptor -------------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x02 (Configuration Descriptor)
wTotalLength             : 0x00EB (235 bytes)
bNumInterfaces           : 0x04 (4 Interfaces)
bConfigurationValue      : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
iConfiguration           : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
bmAttributes             : 0x80
 D7: Reserved, set 1     : 0x01
 D6: Self Powered        : 0x00 (no)
 D5: Remote Wakeup       : 0x00 (no)
 D4..0: Reserved, set 0  : 0x00
MaxPower                 : 0x3C (120 mA)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 02 EB 00 04 01 00 80 3C 09 04 00 00 00 01 01   ........<.......
                           00 00 0A 24 01 00 01 4F 00 02 01 02 0C 24 02 02   ...$...O.....$..
                           01 01 00 02 03 00 00 00 0C 24 02 01 01 02 00 02   .........$......
                           03 00 00 00 09 24 03 03 01 01 00 0A 00 09 24 03   .....$........$.
                           04 01 03 00 05 00 0A 24 06 05 02 01 01 02 02 00   .......$........
                           0A 24 06 06 01 01 03 00 00 00 07 24 05 0A 01 06   .$.........$....
                           00 09 04 01 00 00 01 02 00 00 09 04 01 01 02 01   ................
                           02 00 00 07 24 01 02 01 01 00 0B 24 02 01 02 02   ....$......$....
                           10 01 44 AC 00 09 05 01 05 C8 00 01 00 83 07 25   ..D............%
                           01 00 00 00 00 09 05 83 01 03 00 01 05 00 09 04   ................
                           02 00 00 01 02 00 00 09 04 02 01 01 01 02 00 00   ................
                           07 24 01 03 01 01 00 0B 24 02 01 02 02 10 01 44   .$......$......D
                           AC 00 09 05 81 05 C8 00 01 00 00 07 25 01 00 00   ............%...
                           00 00 09 04 03 00 01 03 00 00 00 09 21 11 01 00   ............!...
                           01 22 6F 00 07 05 84 03 04 00 0A                  ."o........

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x00 (Interface 0)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x00 (Default Control Pipe only)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x01 (Audio)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x01 (Audio Control)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 00 00 00 01 01 00 00                        .........

        ------ Audio Control Interface Header Descriptor ------
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x01 (Header)
bcdADC                   : 0x0100
wTotalLength             : 0x004F (79 bytes)
bInCollection            : 0x02
baInterfaceNr[1]         : 0x01
baInterfaceNr[2]         : 0x02
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 24 01 00 01 4F 00 02 01 02                     .$...O....

        ------- Audio Control Input Terminal Descriptor -------
bLength                  : 0x0C (12 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x02 (Input Terminal)
bTerminalID              : 0x02
wTerminalType            : 0x0101 (USB Streaming)
bAssocTerminal           : 0x00
bNrChannels              : 0x02 (2 channels)
wChannelConfig           : 0x0003 (L, R)
iChannelNames            : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
iTerminal                : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 0C 24 02 02 01 01 00 02 03 00 00 00               .$..........

        ------- Audio Control Input Terminal Descriptor -------
bLength                  : 0x0C (12 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x02 (Input Terminal)
bTerminalID              : 0x01
wTerminalType            : 0x0201 (Microphone)
bAssocTerminal           : 0x00
bNrChannels              : 0x02 (2 channels)
wChannelConfig           : 0x0003 (L, R)
iChannelNames            : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
iTerminal                : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 0C 24 02 01 01 02 00 02 03 00 00 00               .$..........

        ------- Audio Control Output Terminal Descriptor ------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x03 (Output Terminal)
bTerminalID              : 0x03
wTerminalType            : 0x0101 (USB Streaming)
bAssocTerminal           : 0x00 (0)
bSourceID                : 0x0A (10)
iTerminal                : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 24 03 03 01 01 00 0A 00                        .$.......

        ------- Audio Control Output Terminal Descriptor ------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x03 (Output Terminal)
bTerminalID              : 0x04
wTerminalType            : 0x0301 (Speaker)
bAssocTerminal           : 0x00 (0)
bSourceID                : 0x05 (5)
iTerminal                : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 24 03 04 01 03 00 05 00                        .$.......

        -------- Audio Control Feature Unit Descriptor --------
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x06 (Feature Unit)
bUnitID                  : 0x05 (5)
bSourceID                : 0x02 (2)
bControlSize             : 0x01 (1 byte per control)
bmaControls[0]           : 0x01
 D0: Mute                : 1
 D1: Volume              : 0
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
bmaControls[1]           : 0x02
 D0: Mute                : 0
 D1: Volume              : 1
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
bmaControls[2]           : 0x02
 D0: Mute                : 0
 D1: Volume              : 1
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
iFeature                 : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 24 06 05 02 01 01 02 02 00                     .$........

        -------- Audio Control Feature Unit Descriptor --------
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x06 (Feature Unit)
bUnitID                  : 0x06 (6)
bSourceID                : 0x01 (1)
bControlSize             : 0x01 (1 byte per control)
bmaControls[0]           : 0x03
 D0: Mute                : 1
 D1: Volume              : 1
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
bmaControls[1]           : 0x00
 D0: Mute                : 0
 D1: Volume              : 0
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
bmaControls[2]           : 0x00
 D0: Mute                : 0
 D1: Volume              : 0
 D2: Bass                : 0
 D3: Mid                 : 0
 D4: Treble              : 0
 D5: Graphic Equalizer   : 0
 D6: Automatic Gain      : 0
 D7: Delay               : 0
iFeature                 : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 24 06 06 01 01 03 00 00 00                     .$........

        ------- Audio Control Selector Unit Descriptor --------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x05 (Selector Unit)
bUnitID                  : 0x0A
bNrInPins                : 0x01 (1 Input Pin)
baSourceID[1]            : 0x06 (6)
iSelector                : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 24 05 0A 01 06 00                              .$.....

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x01 (Interface 1)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x00 (Default Control Pipe only)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x01 (Audio)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x02 (Audio Streaming)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 01 00 00 01 02 00 00                        .........

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x01 (Interface 1)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x01
bNumEndpoints            : 0x02 (2 Endpoints)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x01 (Audio)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x02 (Audio Streaming)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 01 01 02 01 02 00 00                        .........

        -------- Audio Streaming Interface Descriptor ---------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x01 (AS_GENERAL)
bTerminalLink            : 0x02 (Terminal ID 2)
bDelay                   : 0x01 (1 frame)
wFormatTag               : 0x0001 (PCM)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 24 01 02 01 01 00                              .$.....

        ------- Audio Streaming Format Type Descriptor --------
bLength                  : 0x0B (11 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x02 (Format Type)
bFormatType              : 0x01 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
bNrChannels              : 0x02 (2 channels)
bSubframeSize            : 0x02 (2 bytes per subframe)
bBitResolution           : 0x10 (16 bits per sample)
bSamFreqType             : 0x01 (supports 1 sample frequence)
tSamFreq[1]              : 0x0AC44 (44100 Hz)
Data (HexDump)           : 0B 24 02 01 02 02 10 01 44 AC 00                  .$......D..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x01 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x05 (TransferType=Isochronous  SyncType=Asynchronous  EndpointType=Data)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x00C8 (200 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x01 (1 ms)
bRefresh                 : 0x00
bSynchAddress            : 0x83 (Direction=IN EndpointID=3)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 05 01 05 C8 00 01 00 83                        .........

        ----------- Audio Data Endpoint Descriptor ------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x25 (Audio Endpoint Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x01 (General)
bmAttributes             : 0x00
 D0   : Sampling Freq    : 0x00 (not supported)
 D1   : Pitch            : 0x00 (not supported)
 D6..2: Reserved         : 0x00
 D7   : MaxPacketsOnly   : 0x00 (no)
bLockDelayUnits          : 0x00 (Undefined)
wLockDelay               : 0x0000
Data (HexDump)           : 07 25 01 00 00 00 00                              .%.....

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x83 (Direction=IN EndpointID=3)
bmAttributes             : 0x01 (TransferType=Isochronous  SyncType=None  EndpointType=Data)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0003 (3 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x01 (1 ms)
bRefresh                 : 0x05 (32 ms)
bSynchAddress            : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 09 05 83 01 03 00 01 05 00                        .........

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x02 (Interface 2)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x00 (Default Control Pipe only)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x01 (Audio)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x02 (Audio Streaming)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 02 00 00 01 02 00 00                        .........

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x02 (Interface 2)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x01
bNumEndpoints            : 0x01 (1 Endpoint)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x01 (Audio)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x02 (Audio Streaming)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 02 01 01 01 02 00 00                        .........

        -------- Audio Streaming Interface Descriptor ---------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x01 (AS_GENERAL)
bTerminalLink            : 0x03 (Terminal ID 3)
bDelay                   : 0x01 (1 frame)
wFormatTag               : 0x0001 (PCM)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 24 01 03 01 01 00                              .$.....

        ------- Audio Streaming Format Type Descriptor --------
bLength                  : 0x0B (11 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (Audio Interface Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x02 (Format Type)
bFormatType              : 0x01 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
bNrChannels              : 0x02 (2 channels)
bSubframeSize            : 0x02 (2 bytes per subframe)
bBitResolution           : 0x10 (16 bits per sample)
bSamFreqType             : 0x01 (supports 1 sample frequence)
tSamFreq[1]              : 0x0AC44 (44100 Hz)
Data (HexDump)           : 0B 24 02 01 02 02 10 01 44 AC 00                  .$......D..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x81 (Direction=IN EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x05 (TransferType=Isochronous  SyncType=Asynchronous  EndpointType=Data)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x00C8 (200 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x01 (1 ms)
bRefresh                 : 0x00
bSynchAddress            : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 09 05 81 05 C8 00 01 00 00                        .........

        ----------- Audio Data Endpoint Descriptor ------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x25 (Audio Endpoint Descriptor)
bDescriptorSubtype       : 0x01 (General)
bmAttributes             : 0x00
 D0   : Sampling Freq    : 0x00 (not supported)
 D1   : Pitch            : 0x00 (not supported)
 D6..2: Reserved         : 0x00
 D7   : MaxPacketsOnly   : 0x00 (no)
bLockDelayUnits          : 0x00 (Undefined)
wLockDelay               : 0x0000
Data (HexDump)           : 07 25 01 00 00 00 00                              .%.....

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x03 (Interface 3)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x01 (1 Endpoint)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x03 (HID - Human Interface Device)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x00 (None)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x00 (None)
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 03 00 01 03 00 00 00                        .........

        ------------------- HID Descriptor --------------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x21 (HID Descriptor)
bcdHID                   : 0x0111 (HID Version 1.11)
bCountryCode             : 0x00 (00 = not localized)
bNumDescriptors          : 0x01
Data (HexDump)           : 09 21 11 01 00 01 22 6F 00                        .!...."o.
Descriptor 1:
bDescriptorType          : 0x22 (Class=Report)
wDescriptorLength        : 0x006F (111 bytes)
Error reading descriptor : ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (due to a obscure limitation of the Win32 USB API, see UsbTreeView.txt)

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x84 (Direction=IN EndpointID=4)
bmAttributes             : 0x03 (TransferType=Interrupt)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0004 (4 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x0A (10 ms)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 84 03 04 00 0A                              .......

    ----------------- Device Qualifier Descriptor -----------------
Error                    : ERROR_GEN_FAILURE  (because the device is Full-Speed only)

      -------------------- String Descriptors -------------------
             ------ String Descriptor 0 ------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language ID[0]           : 0x0409 (English - United States)
Data (HexDump)           : 04 03 09 04                                       ....
             ------ String Descriptor 1 ------
bLength                  : 0x1C (28 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Logitech Inc."
Data (HexDump)           : 1C 03 4C 00 6F 00 67 00 69 00 74 00 65 00 63 00   ..L.o.g.i.t.e.c.
                           68 00 20 00 49 00 6E 00 63 00 2E 00               h. .I.n.c...
             ------ String Descriptor 2 ------
bLength                  : 0x2C (44 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Logi USB Headset H340"
Data (HexDump)           : 2C 03 4C 00 6F 00 67 00 69 00 20 00 55 00 53 00   ,.L.o.g.i. .U.S.
                           42 00 20 00 48 00 65 00 61 00 64 00 73 00 65 00   B. .H.e.a.d.s.e.
                           74 00 20 00 48 00 33 00 34 00 30 00               t. .H.3.4.0.
```

My Question from attached descriptor logs:

1. I see only one device descriptor - All good
2. I see only one configuration which match entry in device descriptor. `bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 Configuration)` - All good
3. In the configuration descriptor I see number of interfaces equal to 4. `bNumInterfaces           : 0x04 (4 Interfaces)` - This is where the problem starts. After this I see more than 4 interface descriptors e.g.

   ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------

   ------ Audio Control Interface Header Descriptor ------

   ------- Audio Control Input Terminal Descriptor -------

   ------- Audio Control Selector Unit Descriptor --------

.
.
.
.

And So on

How the number of interface descriptors can be more than 4?

Comment: please do not post links to the text ... add the text to your question ... format as code ... please **no screenshots**

Comment: @jsotola I agree, but since the logs were huge that could hide the actual question so that's why I uploaded the file on dropbox. Will make sure to take care of it next time.

Comment: no, not next time... edit your post now... format the logs as code ... this is for future research and Dropbox links will go dead

Comment: Its not working, i just added the logs. It looks too odd and doesn't recognize the complete logs as code - all new lines are removed. So reverted it. Any way a moderator can do it, please? I am sure I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: did it for you  ... this site is a question and answer site ... instead of saying `its not working` , ask `how to do it?` ... that applies to everything

Comment: First i am gonna say thanks @jsotola. That's most important.

Second may you please tell me how did you do that? :)

Comment: copy from pastebin ... paste into the question ... add ``` before and after the text

Comment: Thanks @jsotola. Following your directions in new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface descriptor is technical term that refers to a very specific piece of data.  This data starts with the bytes 0x09 (length) and 0x04 (the code for "interface descriptor").

Note that things like the "Audio Control Interface Header Descriptor" are not interface descriptors because they do not start with 0x09 0x04.  They are just pieces of data that describe the interface and they go near the interface descriptors.

Your dump shows that you have six interface descriptors:

- An interface descriptor for interface number 0, alternate setting 0.
- An interface descriptor for interface number 1, alternate setting 0.
- An interface descriptor for interface number 1, alternate setting 1.
- An interface descriptor for interface number 2, alternate setting 0.
- An interface descriptor for interface number 2, alternate setting 1.
- An interface descriptor for interface number 3, alternate setting 0.

Since they each describe a different interface or a different alternate setting of an interface, I think it's fine.

See:  [What is an Alternate Setting in a USB interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274535/what-is-an-alternate-setting-in-a-usb-interface)

Comment: Thanks for the details reply. So the other descriptors e.g. `Audio Control Interface Header Descriptor`. How this information can be useful for host as it goes from device descriptor to configuration descriptor to interface descriptor to finally to end point descriptor.

Comment: That question is way too vague.  You can read the documentation of those descriptors in the relevant USB specifications to learn what information is in them and then that will probably tell you whether it is useful.  Also, StackOverflow is not a forum.  If I have answered your original question that you posted at the top, please click the checkmark to accept my answer.